# How to fix error while running setup:upgrade command Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, sql

When I run setup:upgrade then I got this error after Schema creation/updates. If you know any solution then let me know. I have **'wishlist_item'** this table on 461. Thanks

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '**TABLE 461 WHERE
>   `Non_unique` = 1' at line 1**, query was: SHOW INDEXES FROM TABLE 461
>   WHERE `Non_unique` = 1

Comment: did you recently add any new module ?

Comment: No i didn't add any module.